# chrome is not recognizing my content_security_policy string in my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-earth, content-security-policy

I am creating a google chrome extension that uses google earth.

I have added the following to my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Calculator",
  "description": "A simple calculator.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "version": "1.3.2",
  "app": {"background": {"scripts": ["model.js", "view.js", "controller.js"]}},
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16x16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128x128.png"
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com/jsapi; https://www.google.com/uds/?file=earth&v=1; https://www.google.com/uds/api/earth/1.0/109c7b2bae7fe6cc34ea875176165d81/default.I.js; object-src 'self'",


      "permissions": [
          "storage",
          "https://*.google.com/"
        ]     
    }
```

Even still, when I run my extension, I get the following errors:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/jsapi' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/uds/?file=earth&v=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/uds/api/earth/1.0/109c7b2bae7fe6cc34ea875176165d81/default.I.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Try `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com"`

Answer (score 2):

The URLs in your CSP should be seperated by spaces, not semicolons. Semicolons are used to separate directives.

Cf https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#syntax-and-algorithms:

```
 A CSP policy consists of a U+003B SEMICOLON (;) delimited list of directives:
     policy = [ directive *( ";" [ directive ] ) ]
```

So your CSP should read:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com/jsapi https://www.google.com/uds/?file=earth&v=1 https://www.google.com/uds/api/earth/1.0/109c7b2bae7fe6cc34ea875176165d81/default.I.js; object-src 'self'"
```